# In Gtk, is it possible to have one cell renderer per treeview row?

Tags: c, gtk

In Gtk+ it is possible to have several cell renderers per column, however I want to have different cell renderers in different rows. For example, I'd like to list the properties of an object in a tree view. For boolean properties a toggle button would be much simpler to use than editing the `GtkCellRendererText` and type in `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

I know that I can react to the row data by setting a callback via `gtk_tree_view_column_set_cell_data_func()`. But in the callback, the cell renderer is already fixed and I can only change its appearance.

**Edit:** ptomato pointed to how it could be done in Vala. I took this information and build a C-based cell renderer that takes a GObject and a list store (assuming the first column to contain property names) to show a custom cell depending on the type of the property. I also subclassed a tree view widget that combines this for easier usage. Both components can be find at [Github](https://github.com/matze/EggPropertyTreeView).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's [how `dconf-editor` does it](https://git.gnome.org/browse/dconf/tree/editor/dconf-view.vala?id=00926de87b14fd00a1002daedb28b636c2b8b8d1): subclass `GtkCellRenderer` to make a custom renderer, make a property called `renderer` that returns a `GtkCellRendererText`, `GtkCellRendererToggle`, etc. depending on what is needed, and override all the `GtkCellRenderer` signals such as `get_size`, `render`, `activate`, etc. to pass them along to the underlying `renderer`.

It's done in Vala but it shouldn't be too hard to convert to C.

Comment: I am not too fluent in Vala, so I might be wrong with what I hacked together [here](https://github.com/matze/EggPropertyTreeView). It is showing the correct renderers for text and toggle, but not for spin. Moreover, I am not able to interact with the cells in any way, although I set their properties to `"editable"` and `"activatable"`. For some reason the `xxx_start_editing()` and `xxx_activate()` are not called which seems to be the problem.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. I needed to update the mode of the child renderers _and_ the subclassed cell renderer.

Comment: Link is broken since `dconf-editor` was split from `dconf` project.  The linked file still exists in commit [00926de8](https://git.gnome.org/browse/dconf/tree/editor/dconf-view.vala?id=00926de87b14fd00a1002daedb28b636c2b8b8d1)

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the link.